# Is it possible keep alignment / tabulations in MySQL editor?

Tags: mysql, coding-style, editor, mysql-workbench

I'm using the MySQL Workbench for writing some queries.
I would like set the MySQL editor for keeping the alignment or horizontal tabulations in the next line when I press enter for LineFeed. Like the programming editors usually do, I think you what I mean.

I know it has one feature, Format -> Beautify Query, that formats your selection to an other one good formatted, but I prefer to have good style while I'm programming.

I've tried to change the editor settings, but I didn't find the way. Maybe some plug-in can do that.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean auto indentation and no this is not implemented in MySQL Workbench. File a feature request at http://bugs.mysql.com to get this wish into the queue.

Comment: I don't have time right now for creating an account and report a bug. But I regret it of MySQL because I like the editor and I prefer that platform to microsoft SQL.

Comment: @Akronix: not just for this but in general: filing bug reports and feature wishes is essential for open source to be good. Don't take it too easy.